# Accessing localhost on ubuntu 12.04 from Virtual box

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I have virtual host running on my localhost in the /var/www/virtualhost directory. How can i access ubuntu's localhost from the browser on my windows 7 virtual machine ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the network option for your Windows guest to NAT. Once you have done this the default gateway of your Windows machine will be your hosts IP address and you will be able  accessible from your browser.

You can configure the network from the GUI under the VM settings or from the command line with 
VBoxManage modifyvm  nic1 nat

Comment: I fixed it  already. NAT + adding the correct gateway into hosts file in driver. Thanks anyway